# Как у элемента в XSD задать атрибут с определенным числовым типом, значением которого может быть null?

Tags: xsd

Как у элемента в описании XSD задать атрибут с определенным числовым типом, значением которого может быть "" (null)?

В схеме определил

```
<xs:attribute name="Result" type="xs:double" use="required">
```

но в xml документе у атрибута может быть значение ""

```
<Service Result="" />
```

для такого элемента при проверке согласно схемы возникает исключение

```
Атрибут "Result" недействителен: значение "" недействительно с точки зрения его типа данных "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:double" — Строка "" не является допустимым значением Double.
```

Подскажите как можно предусмотреть пустое значение атрибута, присутствие которого обязательно в xml даже с пустым значением, если все остальные значения должны удовлетворять типу double?